# Delete task crud in react

Tags: reactjs

I manage to delete the tasks (you can see it in the console.log) but I don't know how to render the result. I really appreciate your help. Link CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trello-task-forked-2xsh8?file=/src/App.js

```
const addItem = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const item = { id: uuidv4(), content: text };
  const requestedColumnId = Object.entries(columns).find(
    (i) => i[1].name === "Requested"
  )[0];
  const column = columns[requestedColumnId];

  setColumns({
    ...columns,
    [requestedColumnId]: {
      ...column,
      items: [...column.items, item]
    }
  });
  setText("");
};

const deleteItem = id => {
  
  const requestedColumnId = Object.entries(columns).find(
    (i) => i[1].name === "Requested"
  )[0];
  const column = columns[requestedColumnId];

  const arrFiltered = column.items.filter(item => item.id !== id)
  
  console.log('arrFiltered', arrFiltered)

  setColumns({
    ...columns,
    [requestedColumnId]: {
      ...column,
      items: [...column.items]
    }
  });
  
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a straight forward solution. You did it everything correctly but you missed something. Just update your delete function to the following

```
  const deleteItem = (id) => {
    const requestedColumnId = Object.entries(columns).find(
      (i) => i[1].name === "Requested"
    )[0];
    const column = columns[requestedColumnId];

    setColumns({
      ...columns,
      [requestedColumnId]: {
        ...column,
        items: [...column.items.filter((item) => item.id !== id)]
      }
    });
  };
```

Your mistake is that you're filtering the array upon deletion. But you're not updating the main item. So I solved it by adding the array filter in to the main item and removing your filter. Just like this.

```
setColumns({
      ...columns,
      [requestedColumnId]: {
        ...column,
        items: [...column.items.filter((item) => item.id !== id)]
      }
    });
```